# How do I print a webpage while expanding all toggle-div-header?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, html

I want to print this webpage https://www.sbi.co.in/portal/web/govt-banking/senior-citizens in Chrome browser.

The trouble is - I have to manually toggle each sub-section before printing (e.g. 
Senior Citizen Saving Scheme, Eligibility, NRI ..). How can I make all subsections visible at a time and take complete printout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to achieve this is to disable the JavaScript in site settings for this particular site.

Go to `chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sbi.co.in`, which allows you to change site settings for sbi.co.in.

JavaScript is allowed by default so you need to disable it.

[image: disabling javascript]

Refresh the website. Now you can print the webpage with all div's expanded. See my screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceIhT.jpg).

Hope this helps.