# How can I print this webpage with the whole code snippets and without missing image?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, pdf, webpage

I want to print a web page https://www.journaldev.com/3524/spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial into a pdf file.

In Chrome browser, I right click the webpage and choose "print...", and the created pdf file

- doesn't contain the image in "Spring Hibernate Integration Example Project Structure" section
- only contains part of the code snippets which can't be displayed entirely without scrolling the up and down scroll bar

I was wondering if there is some way to print without the above problems? Especially the second problem.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 as my OS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Method**

One way to do this is to edit the css using inspect element. Right click on any of the code snippet in the page and select "Inspect Element".

Now refer below image and uncheck the max-height property from the right page.

[image: uncheck max-height property]

Without refreshing the page press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to print.

> Note: The page goes back to previous state when you refresh the page

*If you want to do the same with other pages on the same site, second method is better than the first method.*

**Second Method**

Other way to achieve this is to disable the JavaScript in site settings for this particular site. But you will miss syntax highlighting in code snippets.

Go to `chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.journaldev.com`, which allows you to change site settings for that site.

JavaScript is allowed by default so you need to disable it.

[image: disabling javascript]

Now reload the webpage and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to print.

> I found some gaps in between when i tried to print. But you can easily
>   remove that using inspect element. See the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-dom).

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/1281730/383350)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain a little why javascript is the cause of my problem?

Comment: Sorry @Tim. I don't know exactly how JavaScript caused a problem in your case. It was actually a guess. I have added one more method which allows you to do this without disabling the JavaScript. If this is answers you question, accept it as answer.

Comment: Thanks. for horizontal scroll bar, I couldn't make your second way work for https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/. Do you have some solution?

Comment: @Tim Second method won't work. Right click on any of the code snippet in the page with horizontal scrollbar and select "Inspect Element". Now uncheck `white-space: pre` property. See the GIF [here](https://i.imgur.com/EelStYu.gif). Without refreshing the page press `Ctrl + P` to print.